# AWS Lambda - events solely on root of S3 bucket

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm writing an automated image resizing tool for S3 using Lambda. I'd like to create thumbnails in a subfolder of the bucket upon a PUT operation but if I put a file anywhere in the bucket the event is fired.

Can some tell me how to make the event on fire on just actions in the root of the specified bucket but no in its subfolders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can configure the S3 notification to fire only on certain paths, so the best option is to implement this logic in your Lambda function:

```js
var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
if (key.indexOf('/') === -1) {
    // No slash in key name, must be in root of bucket, do stuff here
}
```

This will work because if the object is in a subfolder and **not** the root, the key will [have a slash in the name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys).

Comment: Thanks for that. so I guess the downside is that any files I create in subfolders in the bucket using LAMBDA will fire the event and then end up costing me?

Comment: @Leo Yes, unfortunately. However in these cases because your function should exit immediately (and not do any resizing, etc.) the billed duration should be lower.

Answer (score 7):

Use a prefix filter.  For example, configure your trigger with a prefix filter of `uploads/`.  It will fire when `uploads/thumb1.jpg` is created but not when `any_other_prefix/thumb1.jpg` is created.  Then, just make sure when you PUT your thumbnails you use prefix in the key.

[image: Trigger Prefix Filter Example]