# AWS S3 Put event is not working in lower level directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I stored application logs into AWS S3 in following formats.

/MyBucket/TestApplication/Year/Month/Date/mylogs.log

I enabled the event of S3 Bucket "MyBucket".

See the event settings
[image]

But event not fired when new logs come to the log file "mylogs.log"

Comment: What is showing in your Lambda logs? Does the Lambda function work correctly if triggered manually? Are you overwriting an object, or creating new objects?

Comment: I want to call lambda function when new log saved in the S3 bucket, that's all. Invocation count is zero for Lambda Function and no logs in the Cloudwatch.

Comment: AWS Lambda - events solely on root of S3 bucket

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809473/aws-lambda-events-solely-on-root-of-s3-bucket

Comment: You probably should be using `s3:ObjectCreated:*` rather than restricting to just `Put`.  There is more than one way to store an object in bucket and the most likely explanation is that it isn't strictly a "put" operation, so you're filtering it out.

Comment: I setup the event source for the lambda function (s3 bucket name and event type). 
Event Source type : S3 
Bucket : S3-Lambda 
Event Type : Put

See the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/swVeucO.png

Comment: Thank you Michael.
Now the lambda function triggered when I used the Event Type : Object Created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Event Type : ObjectCreated(All) in S3 bucket then Lambda function triggered from lower level directory of the bucket.

Comment: you do manual upload on s3 bucket or using any rest client? 

As i am doing manual upload but trigger is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Event Type : **ObjectCreated(All)** in S3 bucket then Lambda function will trigger. If in any case it is not working then check **your role policy** that You have defined on lambda. This role must have policy to read/write s3.
[image]